# overriding default templates of django-allauth

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-formwizard, django-allauth

I used this social registration/signup library [django allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for a project of mine. How do i customize the default templates and forms to give a better look and feel?

Comment: Check this detailed and easy to follow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773971/8260949

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the latest version of all-auth on github has its templates outside, however the one on Pypi is not, all you need to do is clone the repo in your project directory and override the templates. As simple as that.

Comment: Cloning repository is considered a very bad practice.

Comment: @Red Could you elaborate?

Comment: He probably means that cloning a repo locally means it's more difficult to stay up-to-speed with further updates to all-auth.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you have set a project level templates directory using the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting like:

```python
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
]
```

You should be able to copy all of the folders shown [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates) into that directory and edit them as you need. Most of the templates seem to be filling a `{% block content %}` block, so it's probably easiest if your `site_base.html` template defines that block somewhere.

If you haven't set `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, you can do the same thing, but copy the template folders into the `templates` directory of one of your apps. I prefer to set `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and keep the main site templates like `base.html` there, since they don't really belong to a particular app, but that's really just a preference; the template loader should find them either way.

Comment: In the current version it seems you should have a `base.html` (still with `{% block content%}`).

Comment: ```TEMPLATE_DIRS ``` is deprecated and part of TEMPLATES https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/. Copying templates/anything into package is bad practice and will hurt you later.

Answer (score 13):

In your views:

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView, LoginView


class MySignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'my_signup.html'


class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'my_login.html'
```

Do pay attention to the examples and docs for structuring your own templates.

Watch this piece in the example templates though:

```
<form id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
```

I had to remove the URL link to make it work properly in my own template:

```
<form id="signup_form" method="post" action="">'
```

Comment: Be sure you are pointing your URLs to these replacement views.

Comment: This is the most simple solution that I had on allauth overriding template.

Answer (score 9):

Use the same logic as [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Comment: Whether the link is to 1.9 or 1.10 docs, it's amazing to read "Within this admin directory, create sub-directories named after your app." Name "directories", plural, after your "app", singular?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`example`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/example) application; it has a `templates` folder that indicates the layout of the necessary templates

Comment: well what i have done to implement the library is added a site_base.html in my templates folder with two blocks <!doctype html>
<head>
<title>
{% block head_title %}
{% endblock %}
</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- done for django-allauth -->
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
how do i edit or override the builtin templates, in which directory can i find them inside my virtualenv?

Comment: `~/.virtualenvs/yourproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth`

Answer (score 4):

All of these are good suggestions.

Most of these ought to work.

The only thing that worked for me, though, was to include my own templates in "project/app/templates/account/" and make sure that "django-allauth" gets listed in INSTALLED_APPS *after* my own app.

I discovered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811664/1060339).

Answer (score 2):

To customize django-allauth after installing it, copy it from site-packages and paste it in your project apps directory. In this way the default **allauth** app and its templates being used will be those in your project's **allauth** app. Then if you want to modify **signup.html** of **socialaccount** then go to **apps\allauth\templates\socialaccount\signup.html** and modify it by editting inside 'block content' tag:

```
{% block content %}
    // your customized html for signup form
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think it should work. Because first django looks templates in inside app (apps\my_app\templates\my_app\),  then in project templates directory (templates\my_app\) and then goes to your environments site-packages. Have you tried to change the html in site-packages allauth templates?

Comment: I do not think that copying is a good way. Much better is to `git clone` into project folder rather than duplicating code.

Comment: Copying the templates would be preferred I'm my case, as I'd rather just copy the templates over than clone the repo  with all he code I don't need to modify