# Is there a way to preview django-allauth templates (for styling)

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I'm using django-allauth in an application and would like to customize the templates.

I've copied over a handful of the ones I want to change to my templates directory and it works great for pages like /login that I can view easily with a url, but for all the error states and other things it's really tough as I'd have to login/logout/create/destroy connections with various users in order to see all the templates and style them.

Is there any way to see a list of all of the various template states to make styling easier?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437545/overriding-default-templates-of-django-allauth

Comment: Not really duplicate, but helpful nonetheless