# django allauth how to make a custom design html

Tags: html, django, django-allauth

I know there's a lot of documentation over the topic, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817157/django-allauth-configuration-doubts), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731364/is-there-a-way-to-preview-django-allauth-templates-for-styling) but i couldn't find one that explains so that a 5 year old - or a designer - could understand :) .
My knowledge is html and css, and I need to design the templates for the user login process using Django AllAuth. I'm alone in this one, with no knowledge of python.
Someone please point me to some good documentation to help answering my question: 
1 - How can I design each account/page html if I don't know what element is coming? Do I need to work on the views.py file? (possible to do so without any python knowledge?)
2 - how can I actually test all error messages without having to go thru all the login steps every time?

Thank you, guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this. It was for django-registration, but the idea is the same. 
-Go to github, and clone all the templates. In case, you are not familiar, there will be a folder called templates inside allauth app folder, and download the whole folder. Inside it , there will be base.html, and a folder called allauth. 
-base.html is not needed, and you can delete it. 
-inside all-auth folder, you will have a bunch of self-evident html files. Open the files, now, the only important content lies between {% block content %}{% endblock %}. Copy that to the html files you want, but make sure to have the same file name; otherwise, allauth woent recognize. 
-If you want even more customization, run server, obtain the (soem name)" html codes, and you will see a bunch of html form fiels with id = "(some name)" and name = "". These are HTML fields. As long as you keep the same id and name for each field, you can use them however you want.

Summary: Run server with default allauth templates that you get from github. Go to source of the django generated html files. Copy all the fields that are relevant, and use them however you want.

I know I am not full clear, but it is somewhat a long process.

Here is the official django page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template