# How to edit django-allauth default templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

i'm using Django 1.10 and i want to add the allauth's app for login, signin, etc, to my website. I've installed allauth from pip, and tried to put the templates from allauth repository inside my templates folder and call them but i don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override template in django-allauth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791136/how-to-override-template-in-django-allauth)

Comment: Check this detailed and easy to follow answer stackoverflow.com/a/62773971/8260949

Comment: Use https://github.com/danihodovic/django-allauth-ui

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The correct answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31282443/4992248

1. Create `yourproject/templates/allauth/account/` and paste here all templates you need to edit from `/myproject/Lib/site-packages/allauth/templates/account`.

If you need to make changes for `socialaccount` templates, create also `yourproject/templates/allauth/socialaccount/`

2. Edit `'DIRS'` in `settings.py` like `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth')],`

In the end it should look somethink like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': False,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

3. You never should do any code changes at `/Lib/site-packages/*`, because all changes are lost once a package is updated.

Comment: This did not work for me. Change I need to make were either copy `yourproject/templates/allauth/account/` to `/myproject/Lib/site-packages/allauth/account` or change `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth')` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth', 'templates')`. Hope this helps

Comment: @pravin the 1st way is definitely bad - you will lose all changes during update of `allauth`. Regarding the 2nd way - either you use not standard path or the structure of `django` or `allauth` has been changed (`django` I use very rarely, `allauth` last time I used 1 year ago).

Comment: @TitakFighter, As you stated the problem could be due to changes over different versions over the year. Went through a couple of other solutions given here and other similar question on SO. Most seem to have tried  solution and were not successful in getting it up and end up doing complicated things. However the solution is just a minor tweak to the above solution. Thats the reason for the comment. Thanks

Comment: why would you add `allauth` to your `'DIRS'` when you're putting the new templates under the `template\allauth\account` folder? wouldn't `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` included all sub folders?

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571112/895810

Comment: @dangel it was long time ago. As I remember for some reason it did not work in my case. Unfortunately I do not remember this reason.

Comment: This answer is more clear than the answer in the link it refers to. Other answers elsewhere forget to mention step 1.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me using Django 2.1.7 and django-allauth 0.39.1:

- In the folder `yourapp/templates/` create a folder named `account` so at the end the structure is `yourapp/templates/account/` and add all templates that you want to override like `login.html` or `signup.html`.
- In `settings.py` my Template Dirs remain the same

  `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the documentation of the module is out of date. For Django 1.10 you should do the following:

- download the module with pip
- add the following to INSTALLED_APPS(/settings.py file)

> 

```
'django.contrib.sites', # first place
'allauth',  # after your modules declarations
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
```

- add the backends declarations and another stuff needed by allauth

> ```
> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
> 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
> 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
> )
> SITE_ID = 1
> ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
> ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
> ```

- seems that for django 1.10 is not needed to modify TEMPLATES section (django-allauth==0.28.0). You can verify the modules versions using the "pip freeze" command.
- create an artificial module to override the templates; for example, my project is named irj_app and I've add a new application called _shared, then i have the following structure, and add it to INSTALLED_APPS before 'allauth' declarations :

> `irj_app / _shared`

- i've created a templates directory inside "_shared" folder and i've added a file called "base.html" that overrides the allauth template. what i'd found is that django-allauth creates a template that overrides the layout that you've made before, then you need to intercept the django-allauth templates to change this behavior. Also you can override any template of this authentication mechanism. For example i have:

> `irj_app / _shared / templates / base.html`
>
> `irj_app / _shared / templates / account / base.html`
>
> `irj_app / _shared / templates / account / signup.html`
>
> `irj_app / _shared / templates / _shared / adminlte-template / ... (template for other modules)`

hope it helps

Comment: note that I could not get the above to work when I accidentally had the following directory structure (instead of the above) irj_app / _shared / templates / allauth / base.html  (nb 'allauth' directory)

Answer (score 7):

Try This:

Create **account** directory in your app's template dir so that it looks like below

> yourppname/templates/account

and files

> yourppname/templates/account/login.html
>
> yourppname/templates/account/signup.html

and add below to your TEMPLATE DIRS **Remember to change yourappname to your app's name**

> os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'yourappname', 'templates')

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'yourappname', 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like many have already told here, all we have to do is bring the account,openid and socialaccount folders from the templates folder of allauth into the templates folder of our project folder.

**But one thing to keep in mind while adding the**
 `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_name','templates')]`
to the setting is that, **the BASE_DIR in django points to the directory where manage.py is stored**. And it is at this level we have our project folder and our templates folder within the project. So we need to add our 'project_name' and then 'templates' to the DIRS with os.path.join

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31010966)

Comment: The direct answer has already been posted on this page by multiple people, I'm just sharing a tip to implement that solution properly.

Answer (score 1):

I use django 3.0.4 with django-allauth 0.41.0

Add folder `templates` in your project directory.
Inside the folder `templates` add another folder with the `app_name`, in the case of the template `login.html` you'll create a folder `accounts`

so the full path will be

```
 /project_name/templates/accounts/login.html
```

my TEMPLATE Dirs in `settings.py` remain the same

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

[django-allauth doc templates](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html)

Comment: has to be `account` and not `accounts`

Answer (score 0):

Allauth templates can be overridden just like the normal template overriding methods.

1. Set template directory

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'))`

2. Your template directory will be in project directory. Go inside your template directory and `create a directory named allauth, inside allauth create a template directory and inside that create a directory accounts`
3. Create html files with same name as allauth templates. Refer to [allauth github repository](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates) for more info on template names.

Comment: It returns me that TEMPLATE_* setting is deprecated from version 1.8

Answer (score 0):

> In django-allauth==0.36.0

- let's say you wanna customize the login page.
- don't need to change TEMPLATES setting
- just create a folder named account in your project templates folder then:
- clone the project

  `git clone https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
  cd django-allauth/allauth/templates/account`
- Copy base.html and login.html to the created account folder
- I tried, it works.

[Official Link](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html)

Answer (score -2):

Well, i was just able to do it.

I didn't know where these templates were but i found that, in my case (i'm using virtual env):

```
Envs/myproject/Lib/site-packages/allauth/templates
```

i modified the base.html and added my static folder with all my bootstrap stuff and jquery to the settings in the file:

```
app_settings.py
```

and added this.

```
...
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

And that's all.

I don't know if this is the propper way to do it but if someone have a better answer please post it.

Comment: You should not modify templates in the `Lib/site-packages` directory: if you upgrade the packages, your changes are gone. It also makes it quite difficult to track your changes or to package your modifications. The proper way is to copy the templates to `templates/allauth/`, and add that to the `DIRS` option for `TEMPLATES` in your settings as specified in the other answers.