# Overriden templates aren't rendered in production

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've overriden **Django-allauth** templates in my **Django** project just creating a new folder "account" in templates folder. This works during deployment on Windows but when I moved the project to **DigitalOcean VPS**, it is looking for old templates (in allauth app) so I see old styled allauth pages.

This is the structure:

```
    firstapp\
    authapp\
        templates\
            account\
                 email.html
                 login.html
    anotherapp\
```

I tried to switch `allauth` apps and my `authapp` in **INSTALLED_APPS** but it doesn't seem to work.

And this is my settings.py **INSTALLED_APPS**.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django.contrib.auth',
    'mainapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'super_inlines',
    'django_tables2',
    'quizzesapp',
    'ordersapp',
    'django_extensions',
    'authapp',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',

    'languagesapp',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'localflavor',
    'paypal',
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
    'nested_inline',
    'django_forms_bootstrap'
)
```

What do you thing I should do?

EDIT:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                # 'django.core.context_processors.request',
                # "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                # "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
                # "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",

            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Show your template settings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: put django.contrib.auth at the bottom of the installed_apps and move the custom auth to the top and check again.

Comment: I can't move django.contrib.auth at the bottom. But tried to move authapp right below the django.contrib.auth and it didn't help....

Comment: Did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39091086/709897 ? Especially the section related to the DIRS settings in TEMPLATES

Comment: Try to add 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')] and see if it helps

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov It did not help too.