# Override Template django-allaut

Tags: python, django, django-templates, overriding, django-allauth

I'm almost throwing in the towel with overriding the template. There not way it works for me. Always it's looking the template in the default directory:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/allauth/templates/account
```

I have try almost all that I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811664/3348531
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065009/3348531

my dir structure:

```
myproject
   myproject
   myapp
      templates
         accounts
            login.html
            ...
```

But I also try:

```
 myproject
   myproject
   myapp
      templates
         myapp
            accounts
               login.html
            ...
```

Nothing work

```
--urls.py

   urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
   ...


--settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'formimmapp.apps.FormimmappConfig',
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'formtools',
'crispy_forms',
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),)

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    # 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates')],
    # 'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Django Version

```
1.10.1
```

Comment: what happen when you try with `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/templates', 'allauth')`.. ? and then you can folowing basic template dir of allauth, an example such as `myapp/templates/account/`, `myapp/templates/socialaccount`, or else.. _[for more checkout this](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates)_

Comment: Did you try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy enough mistake to make. Many people add this to the following line to their urls.py and think the templates should go into a folder named accounts

```
 url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

but it does not, this is merely the url mapping for the login urls. The app name comes from

```
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
```

in your django settings.py but what you have is a folder structure with account**s**

```
myproject
   myproject
   myapp
      templates
         myapp
            accounts
```

rename that to account and you will be fine

Comment: Glad to have been of help